# Cannot be resolved to a type?

Tags: java

I'm getting this error for lines with ItemListener and ItemEvent. I put ** where I'm getting it.

```
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JCheckBox;
import javax.swing.Icon;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.JTextField;


public class gui extends JFrame {

private JTextField tf;
private JCheckBox boldbox;
private JCheckBox italicbox;

public gui() {
    super("The title");
    setLayout(new FlowLayout());

    tf = new JTextField("This is a sentence", 20);
    tf.setFont(new Font("Serif", Font.PLAIN, 14));
    add(tf);

    boldbox = new JCheckBox("bold");
    italicbox = new JCheckBox("italic");
    add(boldbox);
    add(italicbox);

    HandlerClass handler = new HandlerClass();
    boldbox.addItemListener(handler);
    italicbox.addItemListener(handler);
}

private class HandlerClass implements *ActionListener* {
    public void itemStateChanged(*ActionEvent* event) {
        Font font = null;

        if (boldbox.isSelected()&& italicbox.isSelected()) 
            font = new Font("Serif", Font.BOLD + Font.ITALIC, 14);
        else if(boldbox.isSelected()) 
                font = new Font("Serif", Font.BOLD, 14);
        else if(italicbox.isSelected())
                    font = new Font("Serif", Font.ITALIC, 14);
        else font = new Font("Serif", Font.PLAIN, 14);

                        tf.setFont(font);
      }
   }            
}
```

Would you help me understand why I'm getting that error ? Person who leads that tutorial don't get these errors.

EDIT:

```
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JCheckBox;
import javax.swing.Icon;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.JTextField;




public class gui extends JFrame {

private JTextField tf;
private JCheckBox boldbox;
private JCheckBox italicbox;

public gui() {
    super("The title");
    setLayout(new FlowLayout());

    tf = new JTextField("This is a sentence", 20);
    tf.setFont(new Font("Serif", Font.PLAIN, 14));
    add(tf);

    boldbox = new JCheckBox("bold");
    italicbox = new JCheckBox("italic");
    add(boldbox);
    add(italicbox);

    HandlerClass handler = new HandlerClass();
    boldbox.addActionListener(handler);
    italicbox.addActionListener(handler);
}

private class HandlerClass implements ActionListener {
    @Override
    public void ActionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
        Font font = null;

        if (boldbox.isSelected()&& italicbox.isSelected()) 
            font = new Font("Serif", Font.BOLD + Font.ITALIC, 14);
        else if(boldbox.isSelected()) 
                font = new Font("Serif", Font.BOLD, 14);
        else if(italicbox.isSelected())
                    font = new Font("Serif", Font.ITALIC, 14);
        else font = new Font("Serif", Font.PLAIN, 14);

                        tf.setFont(font);
    }
}           
}
```

Comment: What is `ItemListener` and `ItemEvent`? Are you missing their import statements and / or their actual definition?

Answer (score 1):

You have to import ItemEvent class.

```java
import java.awt.event.ItemEvent;
```

Comment: I added it among other import statements and one red cross is gone. The red cross for ItemListener is still there.

Answer (score 1):

You should change `ItemListener` to `ActionListener` and `ItemEvent` to `ActionEvent`.

It should look like this:

```
private class HandlerClass implements ActionListener {
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
        Font font = null;
        if (boldbox.isSelected() && italicbox.isSelected()) 
            font = new Font("Serif", Font.BOLD + Font.ITALIC, 14);
        else if(boldbox.isSelected()) 
            font = new Font("Serif", Font.BOLD, 14);
        else if(italicbox.isSelected())
            font = new Font("Serif", Font.ITALIC, 14);
        else font = new Font("Serif", Font.PLAIN, 14);
            tf.setFont(font);
      }
   }            
}
```

Comment: Did that. Now I'm getting "The type gui.HandlerClass must implement the inherited abstract method 
 ActionListener.actionPerformed(ActionEvent)"

Comment: Change `itemStateChanged` method name to `actionPerformed`.

Comment: Now it's saying "The method ActionPerformed(ActionEvent) from the type gui.HandlerClass is never used locally"

Comment: You should add `@Override` above the method declaration.

Comment: Dammit how can I post a code in the comment section ? Will edit my first post then ...

Comment: It seems you haven't changed your method name to `actionPerformed` and you haven't added the `@Override` annotation. Try with the code I added to this answer.

Comment: Try changing your method name to `actionPerformed`.

Comment: Done ... I just don't understand why that guy don't get any errors. His program just works. Grrr...

Comment: Which line? Does it say which method?

Comment: I don't think this is the way to go. I've made quite a bit of changes and get this feeling it's getting worse. I'm trying to contact that guy who did the tutorial ... maybe he'll share with me how come his program works and mine don't.

Comment: The only difference I can see is he runs Windows 7 and I run Ubuntu.

Answer (score 0):

There were 2 Mistakes at your code. 1st is that you should've imported `java.awt.event.ItemListener & ItemEvent` instead of `ActionListener/ActionEvent`. Therefore in your `HandlerClass` declaration you should've implemented `ItemListener` and your event object must be of type `ItemEvent` (at your `itemStateChanged` method)

```
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.event.ItemListener;
import java.awt.event.ItemEvent;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JCheckBox;
import javax.swing.Icon;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.JTextField;


public class gui extends JFrame {

private JTextField tf;
private JCheckBox boldbox;
private JCheckBox italicbox;

public gui() {
    super("The title");
    setLayout(new FlowLayout());

    tf = new JTextField("This is a sentence", 20);
    tf.setFont(new Font("Serif", Font.PLAIN, 14));
    add(tf);

    boldbox = new JCheckBox("bold");
    italicbox = new JCheckBox("italic");
    add(boldbox);
    add(italicbox);

    HandlerClass handler = new HandlerClass();
    boldbox.addItemListener(handler);
    italicbox.addItemListener(handler);
}

private class HandlerClass implements ItemListener {
    public void itemStateChanged(ItemEvent event) {
        Font font = null;

        if (boldbox.isSelected()&& italicbox.isSelected()) 
            font = new Font("Serif", Font.BOLD + Font.ITALIC, 14);
        else if(boldbox.isSelected()) 
                font = new Font("Serif", Font.BOLD, 14);
        else if(italicbox.isSelected())
                    font = new Font("Serif", Font.ITALIC, 14);
        else font = new Font("Serif", Font.PLAIN, 14);

                        tf.setFont(font);
      }
   }            
}
```

This code is what TheNewBoston wrote in his 65th tutorial of Java programming.